# command line argument and default value (how to reset)

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(th(365, 50));// the default value is 365 and 50
      //i want to reset these number from command line 
}
```

i try to use if,else

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] array=new int[args.length];
    if(array[0]==null)  // but incomparable types int and null
         System.out.println(th(365, 50));
    else{
        for (int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
            array[i]=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
         System.out.println(th(array[0], array[1]));
    }
}
```

how to do it.i would really appreciate any help you can give

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: in command line,
if i enter "java aa", the program uses default value,which are 365 and 50 
but if i want to reset these value (enter" java aa 300 50" in command line),the program will use 300 and 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is checking that the number of command line arguments is the one expected, i.e. 2 in your case:

```
if(args.length!=2){
    System.out.println("Two arguments expected!");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Then you can create the array and just parse the input:

```
int[] array=new int[2];
array[0]=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
array[1]=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
System.out.println(th(array[0], array[1]));
```

Of course you should have defined a method called *th* as a member of this class that accepts two integers and returns a String. In addition, if the two input arguments are not integers, an exception will be thrown by the parseInt method.